# Display current top level taxonomy on current single post tye - Wordpress

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

I have to display in the single-portfolio page the top-level taxonomy.

This code works for me only if there is a sub category,
some portfolio items do not have a subcategory and in that case, it doesn't show the parent taxonomy (obviously there isn't a parent taxonomy)

```
<?php
    // variable for location
    $term_list = '';
    $terms     = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_cat' );
    $prefix    = '';

        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
             $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, 'portfolio_cat' );
             $term_list  .= $prefix . $parent_term->name;
             $prefix      = ', ';

            }

        // output
    echo  $term_list;
?>
```

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check child element of current category using `subcategory`, if available then you can ge otherwise print current parent category.

```
<?php
    // variable for location
    $term_list = '';
    $terms     = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_cat' );
    $prefix    = '';

        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
             $parent_term = get_term_children( $term->parent, 'portfolio_cat' );
             if(count($parent_term) > 0){
                 $term_list  .= $prefix . $parent_term->name;
                 $prefix      = ', ';
             }else{
                 $term_list  .= $prefix . $term->name;
                 $prefix      = ', ';
             }
            }

        // output
    echo  $term_list;
?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children

Comment: I have to add  $parent_term = get_term_children( $term->parent, 'portfolio_cat' ); also inside the if, before the $term_list, and now eveything works well! Thank you!